# How do I get to know where a package came from?

Tags: apt, package-management

On systems using `apt`: How do I get to know whether an installed package came from `main`, `contrib` or `non-free`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is

```
apt-cache policy PACKAGE
```

between release and architecture.